# Why is my UIView's frame changing unexpectedly after the embedded UITableView is interacted with?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

Consider the following `UIView` "MainView":

[image]

The view includes a Container View which in turn houses a `UITableView` controller.  The container view's y coordinate starts just beneath the gradient bar.  The `UITableView` includes the section footer at very bottom with the 'STU' label and 'chart' button.

When the `UIView` loads, and up-to-and-until any interaction with the `tableView`, `MainView's` dimensions are:

> Frame: 0.000000x, 0.000000y, 568.000000w, 268.000000h

I have a delegate protocol set up such that tapping the chart button in the `tableView` will create a new view in `MainView` for a shadow effect via a method performing:

```
CGRect newFrame = self.view.frame; // self = MainView
newFrame.size.width = 100;
newFrame.size.height = 50;
UIView *backgroundShadowView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:newFrame];
backgroundShadowView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
// Do Animation
```

The important part above is the 'newFrame' `CGRect`.  For some reason after interacting with the table view by tapping the chart button, or even scrolling or tapping a row, self.view.frame suddenly has the following dimensions:

> Frame: 0.000000x, 52.000000y, 568.000000w, 268.000000h

And so the shadow view appears as follows, with a y origin much farther down than where it would be expected to start, just above the gradient bar.

[image]

I've adjusted the width and height of the "shadowview" for this question; normally it would be 568x268, but would extend 52 units off screen on the bottom because of this issue.

52 units is exactly the height of the statusbar (20) + navigationbar_in_landscape (32).

Of course I could manually adjust the frame dimensions, but I do not want to.  I want to know why the view's frame is changing unexpectedly.

For the life of me, I cannot figure out why the view becomes suddenly offset.  Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: might have something to do with auto layout...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two comments.

(1)

This code was probably always wrong:

```
CGRect newFrame = self.view.frame; // self = MainView
newFrame.size.width = 100;
newFrame.size.height = 50;
UIView *backgroundShadowView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:newFrame];
```

You surely want to define `backgroundShadowView`'s frame in terms of `self.view`'s *bounds*, not its frame as you are doing in the first line here.

(2)

The change in `self.view.frame` is probably illusory. You are probably checking this initially in `viewDidLoad`. But that is too soon; the view has not yet been added to the interface, and so it has not yet been resized to fit the surroundings.

Comment: Coincidentally I just found this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/21793477/2418006 describing much the same thing.  Still, I don't quite understand how bounds is giving any useful information - won't bounds' x and y origins always be 0 since its a coordinate system relative to itself?  This method almost seems the equivalent of manually setting these values to 0, but "it feels better" to do so with bounds since its a property of the parent object :X

Comment: Good call @ your second comment, seems obvious now >.<

Comment: @OneManBand you didn't show enough code for me to be sure, which is why I hedged my answer - it depends what you are _doing_ with `backgroundShadowView`. But if you are making it a subview of `self.view` then I am right, because `backgroundShadowView.frame` is in `self.view.bounds` coordinate system.

Comment: @OneManBand In other words you must _never_ set a subview's frame in terms of its superview's _frame_; you must _always_ set it in terms of its superview's _bounds_. See my discussion of frame and bounds starting here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch14.html#_frame