# rendering a uiview offscreen to capture as a uiimage

Tags: swift, uiview, uiimage

in a personal swift app i am writing, i am using a charting library to create bar charts and display them in a viewcontroller. everything is working fine so far. Now i would like to create other charts, capture them as a uiimage to include in a PDF form ... **without** displaying the charts. The charting library creates a uiview and I tried many of the suggestions.
[post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21793442/drawing-a-uiview-offscreen), and this one [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54691034/can-you-convert-uiview-that-is-not-currently-being-displayed-to-uiimage/54692326#54692326) but without much luck...

this code works but forces me to display the chart

```
    resourceBarChart.updateDataEntries(dataEntries: resChartData, animated: false)
    self.view.addSubview(resourceBarChart)
    let myimage1 = self.view.subviews[1].image(withScale: .native)
```

omitting the display of the uiview

```
    resourceBarChart.updateDataEntries(dataEntries: resChartData, animated: false)
    let myimage = resourceBarChart.image(withScale: .native)
```

returns an empty canvas. i tried playing with the hidden property but without luck (maybe as expected). Being new at this, i suspect there is a subtlety that i am overlooking and open for any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use [drawHierarcy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622589-drawhierarchy) before capture the view as UIImage

```
resourceBarChart.drawHierarchy(in: resourceBarChart.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
```

Comment: Thank you very much ... it worked ! although i am getting this message `[Snapshotting] View (0x7fc7a0d398d0, myApp.BasicBarChart) drawing with afterScreenUpdates:YES inside CoreAnimation commit is not supported.`

Comment: i am not very sure about that message, maybe you can change where you call the drawHierarchy function